# Why isn't my @override for contains working?

Tags: java

```
@Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        if ((this.name).equals((String) o)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I get the error: The method c`ontains(Object)` of type `Team` must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, are you overriding any class implementation, if so, which class?

Comment: Which type does your `Team` extend?

Comment: Your class definition is missing "extends".

Comment: Remove `@Override`, for there is nothing to override.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means there is "no method to override". Your super-class or interface doesn't have a method `boolean contains(Object o)` which the specified method can override.

Answer (score 2):

The method

```
public boolean contains(Object o)
```

must also appear in the super-class or interface of `Team` if the `@Override` annotation is used. The compiler shows that this method *isnt* found.

To fix, you could either remove the `@Override` marker or extend a class that already contains this method.

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answers, an example would be:

```
public interface Team {
    public contains(Object o);
}

public class MyTeam implements Team {     
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        if ((this.name).equals((String) o)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is the same for abstract and non-abstract super types.

As per your error, the [`@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) annotation tells the Java compiler that the following method overrides a method defined in the supertype/interface.